# In my Online multiplayer quiz game how can i make players to join and compete at a time?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am creating a multiplayer Online quiz game in Android Studio using Java. I am having players registered using Firebase in my app. Ok so the main thing is , I'm having different set of quiz tournaments like 10 players tournament, 20 player tournament ,30,40 etc., All tournaments are running one at a time.... For example Consider a 20 players tournament is about to begin, So 20 different players register for the tournament , at a particular time the tournament starts... So the players compete all together at a time and then rank is generated of those 20 players to calculate winning of those players (Rank is generated on the fact who clicked the answer button fastest).

How can I implement this. Most importantly i want to know how can i make the 20 players to play at a time and get the rank of the players of a particular tournament.

Comment: This is a very broad question with a lot of possible answers. I recommend trying something, then come ask for help when you get stuck.

Comment: @Almo Please Can you just suggest me what's the best and easiest way to implement this. Sockets? Firebase? I will try then...Just give me an idea how to do this

Comment: That’s not how this site works. Please read the [help].